# When does NServiceBus bootstrap IProvideConfiguration?

Tags: .net, configuration, soa, nservicebus

New to NServiceBus

I took a little peek into `NServicceBus` it looks for `IProvideConfiguration` in its own internal DI container, but I haven't been able to figure out when in the bootstrapping/ initialization process does the `NServiceBus` Configuration actually search for the marker interface?

Additionally how can I control the process? Eg. making it scan only at a particular assembly?

Also can you override this scanning process and register it on your own against the container and not have it override the instance you provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This requires a bit more investigation but it triggers off calling `.Start()` additionally the order of configuration matters. Which is an annoying oversight - the order of operation during configuration should not matter.Why would it matter if you declare your appsettings first, than the connection string vs. vice versa. But it does in NServiceBus.

So if you use for example if you call `.UnityBuilder(myContainer)` at the beginning, `IProvideConfiguration<>` that you register against myContainer, will be used for your subscription, saga persistence and any other such configuration.

Of course in keeping with good OSS tradition documentation should be kept between nil to a dismal minimum - so they can sell "consulation" services instead. Would have saved me more than a few hours if only someone were to document *the pre and post condition* of the many configuration methods - but no.

Comment: It is true that the execution order still matters and causes a lot of pain to several developers. This problem is known to the development team and in some parts already being addressed.

Answer (score 1):

All the convention interfaces from NServiceBus are picked up during assembly scanning in the With() clause. By default this searches all assemblies in the current appdomain directory. You can limit what should be scanned by using one of the With() overloads, i.ex. Configure.With(AllAssemblies.Except("Legacy.dll"). As I'm aware of the assembly scanning is not pluggable itself.